# Trigger to delete blank rows after INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have inserted a set of data into a database, now I want to delete all the rows with blank values. How can I do this? Can this be done using triggers?

Example:

table BOOKS contains `author_name`, `title`, `price`.

After inserting data, I want to delete all the rows with empty values in the `author_name` column. Here's what I've written so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  AFTER INSERT
  ON  BOOKS
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
  DELETE FROM BOOKS WHERE author_name = ''  
END;
```

This is not working :(

Comment: Is this trigger fired as expected?

Comment: NO ..its showing some syntax error..IS it even possible to delete after insert

Comment: use before insert instead of after insert

Comment: then i will not have access to data before inserting , is there any other workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you've got `BEGIN…END` around a statement not delimited with a `;`. If you put the missing `;`, however, you will need to introduce a *meta* delimiter for the entire definition, because, if you don't do that, the inner `;` will break it.

So, put a `;` at the end of the `DELETE` statement and introduce a `DELIMITER` before the trigger definition:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  AFTER INSERT
  ON  BOOKS
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM BOOKS WHERE author_name = '';
END
$$
```

Alternatively, since the body contains only one statement, you can simply remove the `BEGIN…END`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  AFTER INSERT
  ON  BOOKS
  FOR EACH ROW 
DELETE FROM BOOKS WHERE author_name = '';
```